# AJAX: Passing a string through CGI that contains '&' character

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, cgi

I am creating a website updater. I am passing strings over CGI using AJAX.

**I have a problem where if my strings contain an '&' character they get incorrectly separated because CGI separates parameters/variables by a '&' character**

So if I send this:

```
http://mywebsite.com?user=blah&mystring=I_am_happy_&_sad
```

When I get the variables in my python script the variable mystring will be incorrect:

```
input_data   = cgi.FieldStorage()
user         = input_data.getvalue( "user" ) # correctly = "blah"
mystring     = input_data.getvalue( "mystring" ) # incorectly = "I am happy "
# mystring should = "I am happy & sad"
```

*Now I am using my own post() function in Javascript to send AJAX requests, so I dont use jQuery or anything. Is there a simple way to send strings over CGI that contain '&' in it or will I need to write my own function to parse the string & replace the '&' chars with something else?*

Comment: This must be the fifth time something like this has been asked this week...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to URL-encode the ampersand character:

```
http://mywebsite.com?user=blah&mystring=I_am_happy_%26_sad
```

To do that, Javascript provides [encodeURIComponent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) and Python provides [urllib.quote()](http://docs.python.org/library/urllib.html#urllib.quote).

Comment: See: "How do I convert a string to URL-encoding?" http://www.javascripter.net/faq/escape.htm

Comment: Also see: "How to encode a URL in Javascript?" http://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/how-to-encode-a-url-in-javascript